# Label training data in YOLO

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, yolo

I'm just gettiing into CNNs and Computer vision so I started to research about object detection algorithms, I've read the paper for **Yolov1** and I'm trying to implement the code from scratch using tensorflow (I know it will be difficult but I feel like I learn more this way), however I have a question regarding the training data format.

[image: Yolo Grid]

According to YOLOv1, If I'm trying to recognize let's say 3 Images, the labeling should look something like this:

```
[Objectness,x,y,W,H,c1,c2,c3]
```

Where *c1*, *c2*, *c3* represent the number of classes, in this case 3 (*e.g. human, bike, car*) and *Objectness* represents the confidence that there is an object *1* if there is an object and *0* when there is none...

Using the image above as reference, do I need to label all the *empty cells* as well for this particular image?

```
1st cell, there is no object here    = [0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?]
2nd cell, there is no object here    = [0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?]
3rd cell, there is no object here    = [0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?]
4th cell, there is a black car here  = [1,x,y,W,G,0,0,1]
5th cell, there is no object here    = [0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?]
6th cell, there is a silver car here = [1,x,y,W,G,0,0,1]
7th cell, there is no object here    = [0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?]
8th cell, there is no object here    = [0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?]
9th cell, there is no object here    = [0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?]
```

Or just 2 labels where the objects are contained

```
4th cell, there is a black car here  = [1,x,y,W,G,0,0,1]
6th cell, there is a silver car here = [1,x,y,W,G,0,0,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are supposed to label each cell by yourself. If you look at [AlexeyAB](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects) for example, you can see that each line of annotations is supposed to contain 5 elements:

```
<object-class> <x_center> <y_center> <width> <height>
```

which have relative values. The division of the image into cells and calculating the objectness scores is supposed to happen in the program.

What you mentioned as labeling `[Objectness,x,y,W,H,c1,c2,c3]` is the tensors created at each cell which are then used to train the darknet network.

Comment: Look at Andrew's NG explanation on this video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9s_FpMpdYW8 at 1:02 minutes

He mentions that to construct the training set you go through the cells, thats why I'm confused...

Comment: Yes, but in case of manual annotations, you should only draw a bounding box around each object and set its label. Then in the program you calculate the tensors (based on the annotations and etc) and then feed them to the model for training.

Comment: @SalvadorMolina Prof Andrew Ng explains the general YOLO algorithm, how the coordinates, classes, probs, etc are calculated inside the yolo algorithm. But it doesn't mean you have to annotate your data in such way. Yolo accept the format that has been explained by Hadi above.

Comment: @gameon67 The thing that got to me is that he literally said the following: "To construct the training set you go through each of these 9 grid cells to form the target vector y"... and if you look at the image, the target vector y at that moment has the values I mentioned before, so, in my mind, you had to add the 'objectness' score in order for the network to learn when there is an object there, so I guess my next question would be, how do we know if there is an object in that cell from the training label?

Comment: @SalvadorMolina Check this : https://towardsdatascience.com/yolo-v3-object-detection-53fb7d3bfe6b especially at yolo loss function part. The concept is same with other CNNs and neural networks